# post value one dropdown to other dropdown using php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
include('connection.php');
    $con=mysql_query("select * from province"); ?>
     <select  name="pid" style="float:left; width:135px;">
      <option value="">Select Country</option>
   <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($con)) { 
   $pid=$row['province_id'];

   ?>
     <option  value="<?=$pid?>" ><?php echo $row['province_name'] ?>
     </option>
     <?php } ?>
     </select> - 

      <?php
     $pid=$_POST['$pid'];

     include('connection.php');
      $con=mysql_query("select * from city where city_state ='$pid' ") or die(mysql_error()); ?>
      <select  name="cid" style="float:left; width:135px;">
      <option value="">Select City</option>
   <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($con)) { 
    $cid=$row['city_id'];
   ?>
     <option value="<?=$cid?>" ><?php echo $row['city_name'] ?> <?php  }?>
     </option>
     </select>
```

first table is country table, that coutry id is province_id,
second table is city, that Province id is city_state,
so, post value one to another dropdown

Comment: what do you mean by post value one to another dropdown?

Comment: what issue you are facing ?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @AyyanarG - I think he's looking for a chain select option.

Comment: yes i look chain select option,   Based on Country and City

Comment: based select country and city

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you could use AJAX. In your country dropdown box, just echo all the countries in `<option>` elements.

Then attach a `change` event on this dropdown box using jQuery, so that it will take the user's input (I mean selected country) and do an AJAX request(jQuery has various shorthand methods for AJAX too) to fetch all the provinces belonging to this country. So this request will be sent to a PHP page on your site, that will pull the details from your db using the country id that the user selected.

Then the result from the AJAX request, which would be list of provinces with their IDs is dynamically appended to the second dropdown box(ie. for province). And for this province dropdown box also you would attach a `change` event to it, and do the similar thing like I mentioned above to fetch all the cities under this province, using AJAX.

Do a quick research on AJAX, in Google. There are lots of tutorials to help you.

Comment: dear Akhilesh B Chandran, thank's a lot, ajax method is working on